# Are there performance problems with non-local jumps?

Tags: c, setjmp

I am using non-local jumps (`setjmp`, `longjmp`). I would like to know if it can be a problem for the performances. Does `setjmp` save all the stack, or just some pointers ?

Thanks.

Comment: A performance problem compared to what?

Comment: Compared to goto for example. I know that it's two different things, but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Jens said, if it ever becomes a noticeable bottleneck, redesign it since that is not how `setjmp` is supposed to be used.

As for your question:
This probably depends on which architecture you are running your program on and exactly what the compiler does with your code. On ARM, `goto` is probably translated into a single branch instruction which is quite fast. `setjmp` and `longjmp` on the other hand need to save and restore all registers in order to resume execution after the jump. On an ARMv7-a with NEON support, this would require saving roughly 16 32-bit registers and up to 16 128-bit registers which is quite a bit of extra work compared to a simple branch.

I have no idea if less work is required on x86, but I would suspect that `goto` is a lot cheaper there too.

Answer (score 2):

`setjmp` has to save sufficient information for the program to continue execution when `longjmp` is called.  This will typically consist of the current stack pointer, along with the current values of any other CPU registers that could affect the computation.

I can't comment on whether this causes a "performance problem", because I don't know what you want to compare it against.

Answer (score 2):

The quick answer is: not very likely. If `setjmp` ever becomes a noticeable bottleneck in your program, I'd tend to say your program design needs an overhaul.